# jquery validation of multiselect

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have two multiselect

```
 <select multiple="multiple" name="cselect" id="cselect" class="required" style="width: 240px;">
```

And the other one

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="pselect" id="pselect" class="required" style="width:240px;">
```

I am trying to validate so that atleast one  from ech is selected.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#submit_save').click(function() {
    if(smValidator.form()) {
    } else {
        return false;
    }   
});

var smValidator = $('#form_config_channel').validate({
    rules: {
        cselect: {
            required: true,
        },
        pselect : {
            required: true,
        }
    },
    messages: {
        cselect: {
            required: 'Channel Name: Required',
        },
        pselect: {
            required: "Package Name: Required",
        }
    },
});
```

});

But it is not working. Can someone please point out where is the mistake?

Comment: remove trailing commas for one thing...not working any browser? Are you using IE, in IE those commas will make code fail

Comment: put a demo in jsfiddle.net...can use validation plugin source from microsoft CDN.....  just google it to get link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here's your code in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LETjh/1/) with the information you provided. It seems to work fine. 
Chances are your form selector is wrong or your HTML is not well-formed--you may have to post the full page if you cannot spot the error.

Also note that you don't usually need to manually hook up the validation call, jquery.validate [does it for you](http://jsfiddle.net/LETjh/3/).